# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchALL() on a non-object - using PDO on a Microsoft Access Database

Tags: php, database, pdo

Good Afternoon!

I have made a connection class to a Microsoft Access Database (which works). However my problem lies where I'm trying to use this class to execute a simple SQL statement and I receive the error message: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchALL() on a non-object.

I'm fairly new to PDO and have read a lot of articles online but to no avail. I think I understand my problem but not fully, please could someone shed some light on the situation and possibly provide an answer to why i'm getting the error message?

connectionClass.php

```
class connection{

      public $con;
      private $dbName;

      function __construct(){
          $this->dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "\database\yakety1new.mdb";
       }

      function connect(){
          $this->con = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$this->dbName; Uid=Admin; Pwd=;");
          $this->con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
          return $this->con;
         }   
      }

      if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
      ini_set('display_errors', '1');
      }
```

testIndex.php

```
try{
   include_once '\classes\connectionClass.php';


   $con = new connection();
   $pdoConnection = $con->connect();


   $sql = $pdoConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM celebs");
   $result = $pdoConnection->exec($sql);
     while ($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['firstname'];
       echo $row['surname'];
      }
   } catch (Exception $e){
       echo 'ERROR:'.$e->getMessage();
       file_put_contents('connection.errors.txt', $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND);
       }

       if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
       ini_set('display_errors', '1');
      }
```

The error message is related to this line:

```
while ($row = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is just a boolean that indicates whether the query was successful or not. The `fetchAll` method is on `PDOStatement`, so it should be:

```
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

You're also executing the statement wrong, it should be:

```
$result = $sql->execute();
```

The method you used is for executing a SQL string without first preparing it. You could instead do:

```
$result = $pdoConnection->exec("SELECT * FROM celebs");
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: Thank you! That's gotten rid of the error, however, no results are showing up and I'm receiving this warning:....Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in line 22 - which is-  $result = $pdoConnection->exec($sql);

Comment: Even though it's just a warning, surely it should still show the results of my sql statement?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that you're using `fetchAll` when you should be using `fetch`.

Comment: Just a quick question - why is it fetch instead of fetchAll?

Comment: Because `fetchAll` returns all the rows at once, but you're using a while loop that assigns just one row to `$row`.

Comment: You could instead do `foreach ($sql->fetchAll() as $row)`. `fetchAll` returns all the rows as a 2-dimensional array, and this would loop over them. But if there are lots of results, this is slower and more memory intensive because it has to wait for all the results and fill them into memory.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you for clearing that up. So using a fetchAll is not needed whilst Im using a while loop. You said before that the method I used for executing a SQL without preparing it first but I thought: $result = $pdoConnection->exec($sql); prepares the statement?

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
include_once '\classes\connectionClass.php';
$con = new connection();
$pdoConnection = $con->connect();

$data = $pdoConnection->query("SELECT * FROM celebs")->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
   echo $row['firstname'];
   echo $row['surname'];
}
```

this is all the code you need.