# sql data to json array using PHP gives HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to get data from two database tables using the token I get from the first table I am trying to get the team name in the second table. This then is added to an array to finally print a json array. Have a look at my code below:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbnameabc", $username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM chatbox order by id desc";

$result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$return = [];

foreach ($result as $row) {

    $postid  = $row['id'];
    $token   = $row['token'];
    $gpslat  = $row['gpslat'];
    $gps     = $row['gps'];
    $postmsg = $row['msg'];

    //echo $postid + " is id " + $token + " is token " + $postmsg + " is postmsg " + $gps + " is gps and " + $gpslat;

    $team;

    $sqlx    = "SELECT * FROM logintable WHERE token='$token'";
    $resultx = $dbh->query($sqlx)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


    foreach ($resultx as $rowx) {   
        $team = $rowx['name']; 

    } 

    $return[] = [   
        'postmsg' => $postmsg, 
        'token'   => $token, 
        'gps'     => $gps, 
        'gpslat'  => $gpslat 
    ];

}
$dbh = null;

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
```

Doing the above however throws me an error HTTP ERROR 500. The next thing I should mention is that echo statement I commented above gives me a random number like 10.1421321. So what is the issue? A similar code works fine on another table I had tested but don't know why this doesn't work.

**Update** : There is something wrong with the connection in the second query (`$resultx = $dbh->query($sqlx)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`) because the first one providing fields other than $team are working fine and I can print json if I don't use the second query plus the team name but how do I get the second to work?

Comment: An internal server error means an error log is generated. Have you checked the server's error log for more information?

Comment: Show errors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Additionnaly, it will be nice to provide us with what `var_dump($return)`  after the loop gives.

Comment: Yeah I checked the error log and it says : `Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object` in the line `$resultx = $dbh->query($sqlx)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` @dimlucas @rjdown

Comment: `$dbh->query()` returns `null` that's what the non-object is. Is everything ok with the connection? Try enabling `ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` and catch any exceptions thrown

Comment: Does `$token` happen to have a single quote in it? Also what is the output of `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` right after the query?

Comment: I should tell you that first query works fine. The error is only in `$resultx = $dbh->query($sqlx)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` without the second query the json prints fine. I am trying `print_r($dbh->errorInfo());` but get same error.

Comment: I tried solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23132773/5054460 but I get same error there

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Does it work if you change `$token  = $dbh->quote($row['token']);` **and also by changing the query to** `$sqlx    = "SELECT * FROM logintable WHERE token=$token";` instead of `$token   = $row['token'];`?

Comment: @AlonEitan No that doesn't help. I get the same error.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Are you sure you have a column named `'name'` in your table? Maybe the column name is actually `'name '` (With space)? Make sure that the index key is **exactly** the same as the column name in the table. You can try commenting out the `foreach ($resultx as $rowx) { ... }` to see if the query will execute without errors

Comment: what about concatenation? `$sqlx    = "SELECT * FROM logintable WHERE token=".$token;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with json_encode function. It works fine.

The issue is this line:
$resultx = $dbh->query($sqlx)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

You are calling fetch all on the result of a query, which fails and returns false. Try to run the SQL query in a console/GUI and see what the output is.

If you want to see the specific error returned by PDO use the following function:
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php

Also change your code into 2 lines, to check if query is valid:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query($sqlx);
if($stmt!=false){
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```